# How can I trim certain characters from a string in sql?

Tags: sql, string, varchar, trim

I would like to trim all special characters from a string in SQL. I've seen a bunch of people who use substring methods to remove a certain amount of characters, but in this case the length on each side of the string is unknown.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I see from your other comment that it's *not* what you need. If you say which version of SQL you're using, I can give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `replace` function will help you

i mean to say when you want to remove special char replace this space' ' by using replace function

more about replace : 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

Comment: Replace isn't going to do a trim. What happens if I have something like... #!$#@$#!@Hello,World@!$><?..,@. In a case like that, I'd want to keep the ',' between 'Hello' and 'World'. Or, unlikely but still possible: #%$@#$Hello@!!%#$World@$#$ again, I want to keep the '@!!%#$' between 'Hello' and 'World'. Not quite going to work in that situation.

Comment: yes you are correct in that case but for this u need function like sub string with indexof.

Answer (score 1):

In MS SQL, this will remove all plus signs:

```
SELECT REPLACE(theField, '+', '') FROM theTable
```

Is that the sort of thing you need?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this function  for LEFT trimming any char

```
CREATE FUNCTION TRIMCHAR
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
     @str varchar(200) ,  @chartotrim varchar(1)
)
RETURNS  varchar(200)  
AS
BEGIN



DECLARE @temp varchar(2000)

SET  @temp = @str   

WHILE  CHARINDEX (  @chartotrim  ,  @temp )  =1
BEGIN


SET @temp  = RIGHT( @temp , LEN(@temp)-1) 

END 


RETURN   @temp 

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [YourDataBase]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [Accounts].[fn_CurrentFeeorArrears]    Script Date: 02/18/2014 12:54:15 ******/
/*****Developed By rameez****/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [FN_REMOVE_SPECIAL_CHARACTER] 
(  
 @INPUT_STRING varchar(300))
RETURNS VARCHAR(300)
AS 
BEGIN

--declare @testString varchar(100),
DECLARE @NEWSTRING VARCHAR(100) 
-- set @teststring = '@ram?eez(ali)'
 SET @NEWSTRING = @INPUT_STRING ; 
With SPECIAL_CHARACTER as
(
--SELECT '>' as item
--UNION ALL 
--SELECT '<' as item
--UNION ALL 
--SELECT '(' as item
--UNION ALL 
--SELECT ')' as item
--UNION ALL 
--SELECT '!' as item
--UNION ALL 
--SELECT '?' as item
--UNION ALL 
--SELECT '@' as item
--UNION ALL 
--SELECT '*' as item
--UNION ALL 
--SELECT '%' as item
--UNION ALL 
SELECT '$' as item
 )
SELECT @NEWSTRING = Replace(@NEWSTRING, ITEM, '') FROM SPECIAL_CHARACTER  
return @NEWSTRING 
END
select dbo.[FN_REMOVE_SPECIAL_CHARACTER] ('r$@ameez')
```

Answer (score 0):

this is ONLY for SQL Server 2014 and before. It performs also space trimming on the right, which you may skip it. The while condition is working because it takes advantage of LEN() "bug".

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RTrimCharacter]
(
@Value NVARCHAR(4000),
@CharacterToTrim NVARCHAR(1)
)

RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN

    -- define a temporary nvarchar
    declare @temp nvarchar(4000)
    
    -- copy the input
    set @temp = @Value

    -- rtrim it
    set @temp = RTRIM(@temp)

    while (@Value = @temp)

    begin

        -- set the original to temp
        set @Value = @temp

        -- trim it the last if the character
        if RIGHT(@temp, 1) = @CharacterToTrim
        set @temp  = LEFT( @temp , LEN(@temp)-1) 

        -- additionally trim the spaces
        set @temp = RTRIM(@temp)

    end

    RETURN @temp
END
```